# Convert an RGB image into a Bitmap error in 2.2

Tags: android

Convert an RGB image into bitmap

```
public static Bitmap rgbToBitmap(int[] rgb, int width, int height) {
    if (rgb == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    bitmap.setPixels(rgb, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this way:

> ```
>  Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
> ```

**EDITED:**

You can resolve the `out of memory` issue using the below method:

> ```
>  public static Bitmap shrinkBitmap(String p_file, int p_width, int p_height)
> {
>     BitmapFactory.Options m_bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>     m_bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
>     Bitmap m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p_file, m_bmpFactoryOptions);        
>     int m_heightRatio =
>             (int) Math.ceil(m_bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight / (float) p_height);
>     int m_widthRatio =
>             (int) Math.ceil(m_bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / (float) p_width);        
>     if (m_heightRatio > 1 || m_widthRatio > 1)
>     {
>         if (m_heightRatio > m_widthRatio)
>         {
>             m_bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = m_heightRatio;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             m_bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = m_widthRatio;
>         }
>     }       
>     m_bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
>     m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p_file, m_bmpFactoryOptions);
>     return m_bitmap;
> }
> ```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks.Its not solved.Its throws "Out of memory on a 1327124-byte allocation" error in Htc wildfire 2.2.1

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But how can i use in above(Bitmap rgbToBitmap) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() with the devices width and height the image is overloading the budget of memory